# How is the loss of wgan-gp good?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I encountered some problems when training wgan-gp. I don't know what kind of discriminator and generator loss curve is good.
My own understanding is that the loss of the discriminator should be close to 0, and the loss of the generator should continue to increase.
Now I get the following loss curve.
[image]
[image]
As far as my own understanding is concerned, the discriminator is well trained, but there is a problem with the generator training. Is my understanding correct?
The following is the loss function：
[image]